# Delete object from an array if the key value match

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this object

```
obj = [
 {id: 145, value: '$ 1.024.100'}
 {id: 146, value: '$ 679.200'}
 {id: 147, value: '$ 679.200'}
]
```

From a checkbox I'm getting a value and id, I'm trying that if that value and id match remove the array that match

So I'm looking that if the value and id that I send is for example `$ 679.200` and `146` the `obj` result is this

```
obj = [
 {id: 145, value: '$ 1.024.100'}
 {id: 147, value: '$ 679.200'}
]
```

I tried this but doesn't work

```
var index: number = obj.indexOf(ob.source.value, id);
obj.splice(index, 1);
```

It delete it but not the value and id that match

any help I will appreciate

Comment: `I have this object`: it's an array.

Comment: `typeof [] === 'object'` technically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const removeElemWithIdAndValue = (arr = [], targetId, targetValue) => {
  const index = arr.findIndex(({ id, value }) => id === targetId && value === targetValue);
  if(index >= 0) arr.splice(index, 1);
}

const arr = [ {id: 145, value: '$ 1.024.100'}, {id: 146, value: '$ 679.200'}, {id: 147, value: '$ 679.200'} ];
removeElemWithIdAndValue(arr, 1461, '$ 679.200');
console.log(arr);
```